# Syntax Error in SQL?? Where?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

```
SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`,
       `bio_community_events`.`begin_on`,
       `bio_community_events`.`name`
  FROM `bio_community_events`
  JOIN `bio_contacts`
    ON (`bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = `bio_community_events`.`user_id`)
  JOIN `bio_community_groups`
    ON (`bio_community_groups`.`id` = `bio_community_events`.`group_id`)
 WHERE `bio_contacts`.`user_id` = '33'
 WHERE `bio_community_events`.`group_id` = '1'
 LIMIT 10

UNION ALL

SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`,
       `bio_community_events`.`begin_on`,
       `bio_community_events`.`name`
  FROM `bio_community_events`
  JOIN `bio_contacts`
    ON (`bio_contacts`.`user_id` = `bio_community_events`.`user_id`)
  JOIN `bio_community_groups`
    ON (`bio_community_groups`.`id` = `bio_community_events`.`group_id`)
 WHERE `bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = '33'
 WHERE `bio_community_events`.`group_id` = '1'
 LIMIT 10
```

It says:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE
>   `bio_community_events`.`group_id` =
>   '1'

I can't find the syntax mistake!

**Edit:**

I wrapped all into brackets and add "AND WHERE". Not working... still the same error.

New query:

```
SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`,
`bio_community_events`.`begin_on`,
`bio_community_events`.`name`
FROM `bio_community_events`
JOIN `bio_contacts`
ON (`bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = `bio_community_events`.`user_id`)
JOIN `bio_community_groups`
ON (`bio_community_groups`.`id` = `bio_community_events`.`group_id`)
WHERE (`bio_contacts`.`user_id` = '33')
AND WHERE (`bio_community_events`.`group_id` = '1')
LIMIT 10

UNION ALL

SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`,
`bio_community_events`.`begin_on`,
`bio_community_events`.`name`
FROM `bio_community_events`
JOIN `bio_contacts`
ON (`bio_contacts`.`user_id` = `bio_community_events`.`user_id`)
JOIN `bio_community_groups`
ON (`bio_community_groups`.`id` = `bio_community_events`.`group_id`)
WHERE (`bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = '33')
AND WHERE (`bio_community_events`.`group_id` = '1')
LIMIT 10
```

**Edit #2:**

I looked at your example. Stupid me! Thanks.

Comment: The clue is in the question, well, the title of the question actually! ;-)

Comment: To you edit: You only need one `WHERE`, like the example in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 `WHERE` clauses, you need to replace your second `WHERE` with an `AND` or `OR`.

**Edit:** like ypercube pointed out, you have the error in both subqueries of the `UNION`-clause.

For example:

```
SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`,
   `bio_community_events`.`begin_on`,
   `bio_community_events`.`name`
FROM `bio_community_events`
JOIN `bio_contacts`
    ON (`bio_contacts`.`user_id` = `bio_community_events`.`user_id`)
JOIN `bio_community_groups`
    ON (`bio_community_groups`.`id` = `bio_community_events`.`group_id`)
WHERE `bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = '33'
AND `bio_community_events`.`group_id` = '1'
LIMIT 10
```

**Edit 2:**

A `WHERE` clause takes a boolean  expression. You can only have one `WHERE` clause per query.

[SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

[Expression syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/expressions.html)

If you want to connect 2 expressions, you have to use `OR` or `AND`, etc.
You don't need to write another `WHERE` clause. It all goes into one `WHERE`.

Comment: Did it. I even wrap all where clause in brackets. For both. Not working... see my edit.